# Is it possible to map the same physical memory to multiple virtual address spaces within the same process?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, mmap

On Windows, there is a `CreateFileMapping` API which allows for creating a block of memory which may be backed by a file and `MapViewOfFile` which allows for mapping parts of the file, even the same parts to multiple virtual memory regions. Here's an example program

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Create a file mapping object for shared memory
    HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 256, L"MySharedMemory");
    if (hMapFile == NULL) {
        printf("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Map a view of the file mapping into the current process
    LPVOID p1 = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 256);
    if (p1 == NULL) {
        printf("Could not map view of file (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return 1;
    }

    // Map another view of the same file mapping into the current process
    LPVOID p2 = MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 256);
    if (p2 == NULL) {
        printf("Could not map view of file (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        UnmapViewOfFile(p1);
        CloseHandle(hMapFile);
        return 1;
    }

    // Use the memory regions via p1 and p2
    strcpy((char*)p1, "Hello, world!");
    printf("p2 sees: %s\n", (char*)p2);

    // Clean up
    UnmapViewOfFile(p1);
    UnmapViewOfFile(p2);
    CloseHandle(hMapFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to do this on Linux and macOS? What APIs would I need to use? It seems like mmap doesn't have a concept of a file handle for non-file backed mapped memory.

Comment: What's the use case for this?

Comment: A non-file-backed mapping is called an anonymous mapping in Linux.  Use the MAP_ANONYMOUS flag.

Comment: @Barmar This ring buffer trick: https://abhinavag.medium.com/a-fast-circular-ring-buffer-4d102ef4d4a3 The blog has an implementation showing how to do this with mmap. I will write an answer after I verify this works and try with shared memory to avoid the file.

Comment: Try creating a `memfd` with [`memfd_create()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html) instead of a temporary file (on Linux).